# Facing issue while using “Publish Over CIFS Plugin” jenkins plugin?

Tags: windows, jenkins, iis, devops, cifs

I am using Jenkins on a Windows machine to build my `.Net` code and to    publish artifacts on an IIS server hosted on a remote windows server.

In this process I followed the following steps, but no file has been transferred.

1. Installed Jenkins, Visual Studio and all required plugins.
2. Configured MSBuild to Jenkins and succeeded up to build process.
3. Installed "Publish Over CIFS Plugin" and get succeeded in establishing connection b/w Jenkins and remote servers.

#### Jenkins general config > Publish over CIFS > CIFS Share

> Name: jenkispush
>
> Hostname: IPv4 address
>
> Username: Admin
>
> Password: *********
>
> Share: jenkins
>
> **Success** Test configuration

#### Job > Post-build Actions > Send build artifacts to a windows share > CIFS Share

> Name: jenkispush
>
> Source files: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\pncreengineerin
>
> Remove prefix: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\pncreengineerin
>
> Remote directory: $JENKINS_HOME
>
> Exclude files:
>
> Pattern separator: [, ]+
>
> …
>
> Remote directory is a date format: [x]
>
> …

#### Job success log

```
Time Elapsed 00:00:05.67
CIFS: Connecting from host [NYMCHNCPU326]
CIFS: Connecting with configuration [jenkispush] ...
CIFS: Disconnecting configuration [jenkispush] ...
CIFS: Transferred 0 file(s)
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: It get succeed for be using pipeline script for CISF plugin.

Comment: Good to know, maybe the front end is bugged but not the Groovy part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got succeeded with this plugin by using pipeline job.

steps to configure pipeline job:

1. create a pipeline job.
2. Select "cifsPublisher: Send build artifacts to windows share" option from sample step
3. give CIFS share name i.e., is configured in "configure system"
4. fill "source file", "remove prefix", "remote directory" (remote directory is a shared folder in remote server) and generate syntax.

ex syntax: cifsPublisher(publishers: [[configName: 'XXX-Green-SERVER', transfers: [[cleanRemote: false, excludes: '', flatten: false, makeEmptyDirs: false, noDefaultExcludes: false, patternSeparator: '[, ]+', remoteDirectory: 'configuration', remoteDirectorySDF: false, removePrefix: '', sourceFiles: 'configuration.zip']], usePromotionTimestamp: false, useWorkspaceInPromotion: false, verbose: false]])

in above example

source file: configuration.zip

remote directory(shared folder): configuration